# C++ PROJ.4 Geographic information manipulation

Tags: c++

I am trying to include the C++ library PROJ.4 in my C++ project for manipulating map data. So far I have not been able to make any headway.

I am wondering if there is a good samaritan out there with experience integrating PROJ.4 in their projects on Windows. Do you have a step by step knowledge of how to integrate the source code into your project?

The downloaded file has an "src" folder separate from an "include" folder. Their website says to include the header "proj.h" which is located in the "src" folder. I tried that in a Sandbox to no avail.

I am missing the steps to prepare the source code to integrate in my C++ project. If anyone has gone through the steps from the source code and can walk me through it, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <C:\PROJ4\src\proj.h>

int main(void) {
    PJ_CONTEXT* C;
    PJ* P;
    PJ* P_for_GIS;
    PJ_COORD a, b;
    C = proj_context_create();

    P = proj_create_crs_to_crs(C,
        "EPSG:4326",
        "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84", /* or EPSG:32632 */
        NULL);

    if (0 == P) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* This will ensure that the order of coordinates for the input CRS */
    /* will be longitude, latitude, whereas EPSG:4326 mandates latitude, */
    /* longitude */
    P_for_GIS = proj_normalize_for_visualization(C, P);
    if (0 == P_for_GIS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Oops\n");
        return 1;
    }
    proj_destroy(P);
    P = P_for_GIS;

    /* a coordinate union representing Copenhagen: 55d N, 12d E    */
    /* Given that we have used proj_normalize_for_visualization(), the order of
    /* coordinates is longitude, latitude, and values are expressed in degrees. */
    a = proj_coord(12, 55, 0, 0);

    /* transform to UTM zone 32, then back to geographical */
    b = proj_trans(P, PJ_FWD, a);
    printf("easting: %.3f, northing: %.3f\n", b.enu.e, b.enu.n);
    b = proj_trans(P, PJ_INV, b);
    printf("longitude: %g, latitude: %g\n", b.lp.lam, b.lp.phi);

    /* Clean up */
    proj_destroy(P);
    proj_context_destroy(C); /* may be omitted in the single threaded case */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _proj_context_create referenced in function _main

Comment: `unresolved external symbol _proj_context_create` tells you that while the compiler knows the declaration (given in the header) the definition is missing in the linking step. In the case of a function that is provided by a library, this tells you that didn't link against the library.